# TypeError when printing the result from input()

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I'm using python 3.3 and I'm trying to use the %s function but I get an error. I put 
`print("you're a %s man") % (input("put an adjective"))`

then I run it in the module and get this

`you're a %s man
put an adjectivefunny
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\coding\mie.py", line 1, in <module>
    print("you're a %s man") % (input("put an adjective"))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'str'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct syntax:

```
>>> print("you're a %s man" % input("put an adjective: "))
put an adjective: foo
you're a foo man
```

`print()` returns `None` in py3.x, so you were trying to apply string formatting to that `None`.

```
>>> None % "foo"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-2-1aa4f0c0cbbd>", line 1, in <module>
    None % "foo"
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```